# Pandas: Wide to long transformation: how to get the row and col numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Beginner question : 
I have a matrix of lets say 3x3 and I want to convert it to the long format as follows :

Wide :

```
    A      B    C
A   0.1    0.2    0.3
B   0.1    0.2    0.3 
C   0.1    0.2    0.3
```

Long :

```
    Col1  Col2  Row_num Col_num Value

0   A     A     1        1     0.1
1   A     B     1        2     0.2
2   A     C     1        3     0.3
.
.
8   C     C     3        3     0.3
```

I have tried various functions like melt, unstack(),wide_to_long but can't get the col number. What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create data and unstack values**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
                   'B': [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
                   'C': [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]}, 
                   index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
mapping = {col: idx for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns, 1)}
df = df.unstack().to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Value']
```

**DataFrame**

```
>>> df

    Col1  Col2  Value
0   A     A     0.1
1   A     B     0.1
2   A     C     0.1
3   B     A     0.2
4   B     B     0.2
5   B     C     0.2
6   C     A     0.3
7   C     B     0.3
8   C     C     0.3
```

**Map remaining values**

```py
>>> df.assign(
        Row_num=df['Col1'].map(mapping),
        Col_num=df['Col2'].map(mapping)
    )
```

**Output**

```
    Col1  Col2  Value Row_num Col_num
0   A     A     0.1   1    1
1   A     B     0.1   1    2
2   A     C     0.1   1    3
3   B     A     0.2   2    1
4   B     B     0.2   2    2
5   B     C     0.2   2    3
6   C     A     0.3   3    1
7   C     B     0.3   3    2
8   C     C     0.3   3    3
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer.. I think you misunderstood the ques, so I have updated with different values and col names. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this since my method involves two for loops but this is a quick and dirty way to transform the data like you're looking for:

```
# df is your initial dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,1],
                   "B": [2,2,2],
                   "C": [3,3,3]}, 
                   index=["A","B","C"])

#long_rows will store the data we need for the new df
long_rows = []

# loop through each row 
for i in range(len(df)):

    #loop through each column
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):

        ind = list(df.index.values)[i]
        col = list(df.columns.values)[j]
        val = df.iloc[i,j]
        row = [ind, col, i+1, j+1, val]
        long_rows.append(row)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(long_rows, columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Row1", "Row2", "Value"])
```

and the result:

```
new_df
    Col1    Col2    Row1    Row2    Value
0   A       A       1       1       1
1   A       B       1       2       2
2   A       C       1       3       3
3   B       A       2       1       1
4   B       B       2       2       2
5   B       C       2       3       3
6   C       A       3       1       1
7   C       B       3       2       2
8   C       C       3       3       3
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this works. But as you said, there might be a more sleek method. But really appreciate your answer. Thanks